# i don't know why these 2 codes have different outputs in python

Tags: python-3.x

this is for a tic tac toe game for my project but I still don't under stand the difference between my code and my mentor's code
correct code:

```py
def player_input():
    marker = ''

    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = input('Player 1: Do you want to be X or O? ').upper()

    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X', 'O')
    else:
        return ('O', 'X')
```

my code:

```py
def player_input():
    player1 = ""
    while player1 != "X" or player1 !="O":
        player1 = input("choose x or o : ").upper()

    if player1 == "X":
       return ("X","O")
    else:
        return ("O", "X")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your condition should have `and` and not `or`.

As per de morgans law:

```
~(p or q) => ~p and ~q
```

So your code should be as follows:

```py
def player_input():
    player1 = ""
    while player1 != "X" and player1 !="O":
        player1 = input("choose x or o : ").upper()

    if player1 == "X":
       return ("X","O")
    else:
        return ("O", "X")
```